# Ring Buffer Implementation in C++14

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++14, collections, circular-list

A ring buffer or circular buffer is a fixed sized queue that advances head and tail pointers in a modulo manner rather than moving the data. Ring buffers are often used in embedded computer design.

This implementation of a c++14 compatible Ring Buffer that was inspired by a [Pete Goodliffe's ACCU article](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/389) and the  [Chris Riesbeck web page](https://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterator-define.html).

As a hobbyist programmer, I started this project so I could learn some more about using templates. I intentionally avoided allocators since I don’t fully understand them (yet). I also did not attempt “emplace_back” for the same reason, but would love to learn about this. I used default copy/move constructors. Any suggestions or feedback that I can get about style, design and completeness of class will be appreciated. I believe that the iterator is basically STL compatible, but I would enjoy feedback on this aspect of the project as well.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>


template <class T>
class ring
{
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T & ;
    using const_reference = const T &;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using circularBuffer = std::vector<value_type>;

    circularBuffer m_array;
    size_type m_head;
    size_type m_tail;
    size_type m_contents_size;
    const size_type m_array_size;
public:

    ring(size_type size = 8) : m_array(size),
        m_array_size(size),
        m_head(1),
        m_tail(0),
        m_contents_size(0) {
        assert(m_array_size > 1 && "size must be greater than 1");
    }
    ring(std::initializer_list<T> l) :m_array(l),
        m_array_size(l.size()),
        m_head(0),
        m_tail(l.size() - 1),
        m_contents_size(l.size()) {
        assert(m_array_size > 1 && "size must be greater than 1");
    }

    template <bool isconst> struct my_iterator;
    reference front() { return m_array[m_head]; }
    reference top() { return front(); }
    reference back() { return m_array[m_tail]; }
    const_reference front() const { return m_array[m_head]; }
    const_reference back() const { return m_array[m_tail]; }
    void clear();
    void push_back(const value_type &item);
    void push(const value_type &item) { push_back(item); }
    void pop_front() { increment_head(); }
    void pop() { pop_front(); }
    size_type size() const { return m_contents_size; }
    size_type capacity() const { return m_array_size; }
    bool empty() const;
    bool full() const;

    size_type max_size() const { return size_type(-1) / sizeof(value_type); }
    reference operator[](size_type index);
    const_reference operator[](size_type index) const;
    reference at(size_type index);
    const_reference at(size_type index) const;

    using iterator = my_iterator<false>;
    using const_iterator = my_iterator<true>;
    iterator begin();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator cbegin() const;
    iterator rbegin();
    const_iterator rbegin() const;
    iterator end();
    const_iterator end() const;
    const_iterator cend() const;
    iterator rend();
    const_iterator rend() const;

private:
    void increment_tail();
    void increment_head();

    template <bool isconst = false>
    struct my_iterator
    {
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = long long;
        using reference = typename std::conditional_t< isconst, T const &, T & >;
        using pointer = typename std::conditional_t< isconst, T const *, T * >;
        using vec_pointer = typename std::conditional_t<isconst, std::vector<T> const *, std::vector<T> *>;
    private:
        vec_pointer ptrToBuffer;
        size_type offset;
        size_type index;
        bool reverse;

        bool comparable(const my_iterator & other) {
            return (reverse == other.reverse);
        }

    public:
        my_iterator() : ptrToBuffer(nullptr), offset(0), index(0), reverse(false) {}  //
        my_iterator(const ring<T>::my_iterator<false>& i) :
            ptrToBuffer(i.ptrToBuffer),
            offset(i.offset),
            index(i.index),
            reverse(i.reverse) {}
        reference operator*() { 
            if (reverse) 
                return (*ptrToBuffer)[(ptrToBuffer->size() + offset - index) % (ptrToBuffer->size())];
            return (*ptrToBuffer)[(offset+index)%(ptrToBuffer->size())]; 
        }
        reference operator[](size_type index) {
            my_iterator iter = *this;
            iter.index += index;
            return *iter;
        }
        pointer operator->() { return &(operator *()); }

        my_iterator& operator++ ()
        {
            ++index;
            return *this;
        };
        my_iterator operator ++(int)
        {
            my_iterator iter = *this;
            ++index;
            return iter;
        }
        my_iterator& operator --()
        {
            --index;
            return *this;
        }
        my_iterator operator --(int) {
            my_iterator iter = *this;
            --index;
            return iter;
        }
        friend my_iterator operator+(my_iterator lhs, int rhs) {
            lhs.index += rhs;
            return lhs;
        }
        friend my_iterator operator+(int lhs, my_iterator rhs) {
            rhs.index += lhs;
            return rhs;
        }
        my_iterator& operator+=(int n) {
            index += n;
            return *this;
        }
        friend my_iterator operator-(my_iterator lhs, int rhs) {
            lhs.index -= rhs;
            return lhs;
        }
        friend difference_type operator-(const my_iterator& lhs, const my_iterator& rhs) {
            lhs.index -= rhs;
            return lhs.index - rhs.index;
        }
        my_iterator& operator-=(int n) {
            index -= n;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator==(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other)) 
                return (index + offset == other.index + other.offset);
            return false;
        }
        bool operator!=(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other)) return !this->operator==(other);
            return true;
        }
        bool operator<(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if(comparable(other)) 
                return (index + offset < other.index + other.offset);
            return false;
        }
        bool operator<=(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if(comparable(other)) 
                return (index + offset <= other.index + other.offset);
            return false;
        }
        bool operator >(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other)) return !this->operator<=(other);
            return false;
        }
        bool operator>=(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other)) return !this->operator<(other);
            return false;
        }
        friend class ring<T>;
    };
};

template<class T>
void ring<T>::push_back(const value_type & item)
{
    increment_tail();
    if (m_contents_size > m_array_size) increment_head(); // > full, == comma
    m_array[m_tail] = item;
}

template<class T>
void ring<T>::clear()
{
    m_head = 1;
    m_tail = m_contents_size = 0;
}

template<class T>
bool ring<T>::empty() const
{
    if (m_contents_size == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

template<class T>
inline bool ring<T>::full() const
{
    if (m_contents_size == m_array_size) return true; 
    return false;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_reference ring<T>::operator[](size_type index) const
{
    index += m_head;
    index %= m_array_size;
    return m_array[index];
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::reference ring<T>::operator[](size_type index)
{
    const ring<T>& constMe = *this;
    return const_cast<reference>(constMe.operator[](index));
    //  return const_cast<reference>(static_cast<const ring<T>&>(*this)[index]);
}
//*/

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::reference ring<T>::at(size_type index)
{
    if (index < m_contents_size) return this->operator[](index);
    throw std::out_of_range("index too large");
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_reference ring<T>::at(size_type index) const
{
    if (index < m_contents_size) return this->operator[](index);
    throw std::out_of_range("index too large");
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::iterator ring<T>::begin()
{
    iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::begin() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::cbegin() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::iterator ring<T>::rbegin()
{
    iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_tail;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = true;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::rbegin() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_tail;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = true;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::iterator ring<T>::end()
{
    iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::end() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::cend() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::iterator ring<T>::rend()
{
    iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_tail;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = true;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::rend() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_tail;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = true;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
void ring<T>::increment_tail()
{
    ++m_tail;
    ++m_contents_size;
    if (m_tail == m_array_size) m_tail = 0;
}

template<class T>
void ring<T>::increment_head()
{
    if (m_contents_size == 0) return;
    ++m_head;
    --m_contents_size;
    if (m_head == m_array_size) m_head = 0;
}
```

Here is the code that I used to test stuff out.

```
int main()
{
    ring<int> mybuf(10);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        mybuf.push(i);
        for (auto i = mybuf.begin(); i != mybuf.end(); ++i) cout << *i << ": ";
        if (mybuf.full()) cout << "full";
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << "Buffer Size: " << mybuf.size() << '\n';
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mybuf.size() + 1; ++i) {
        try
        {
            cout << mybuf.at(i) << ": ";
        }
        catch (std::exception e)
        {
            cout << e.what() << '\n';
            continue;
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
    auto start = mybuf.begin();
    start += 1;
    cout << "start++: " << *start << '\n';
    ring<int>::const_iterator cstart(start);
    cout << "cstart(start)++: " << *(++cstart) << '\n';
    cout << "--start: " << *(--start) << '\n';
    if (start == mybuf.begin()) cout << "Start is mybuf.begin\n";
    else cout << "Lost!\n";
    cout << "Push!\n";
    mybuf.push(100);
    if (start == mybuf.begin()) cout << "In the begining :-)\n";
    else cout << "Start is no longer mybuf.begin\n";
    start = mybuf.begin();
    cout << "after push, start: " << *start << '\n';
    cout << "forwards:  ";
    for (auto i = mybuf.begin(); i < mybuf.end(); i+=2) cout << *i << ": ";
    cout << '\n';
    cout << "backwards: ";
    for (auto i = mybuf.rbegin(); i < mybuf.rend(); i+=2) cout << *i << ": ";
    cout << '\n';
    cout << "mybuf[0]: "<<mybuf[0] << " " << "\nPush!\n\n";
    mybuf.push(20);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mybuf.size(); ++i) cout << mybuf[i] << ": ";
    cout << '\n';
    cout << "pop: " << mybuf.top() << '\n';
    mybuf.pop();
    cout << "new front: " << mybuf[0] << " new size: ";
    cout << mybuf.size() << '\n';
    cstart = mybuf.end();
    cout << "last: " << *(--cstart) << '\n';
    for (auto i = mybuf.begin(); i != mybuf.end(); ++i) cout << *i << ": ";
    cout << '\n';
    cout << "pop again: " << mybuf.front() << '\n';
    mybuf.pop();
    cstart = mybuf.rbegin();
    cout << "last: " << *cstart << '\n';
    for (auto i = mybuf.begin(); i != mybuf.end(); ++i) cout << *i << ": ";
    cout << "\n\nclone: ";
    ring<int> cbuf(mybuf);
    for (auto i = std::find(mybuf.begin(),mybuf.end(),100); i != cbuf.end(); ++i) cout << *i << ": ";
    auto iter = cbuf.cbegin();
    cout << "\nbegin[3] = " << iter[3];
    cout << '\n' << '\n';
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

And this is the output from that test.

```
0:
0: 1:
0: 1: 2:
0: 1: 2: 3:
0: 1: 2: 3: 4:
0: 1: 2: 3: 4: 5:
0: 1: 2: 3: 4: 5: 6:
0: 1: 2: 3: 4: 5: 6: 7:
0: 1: 2: 3: 4: 5: 6: 7: 8:
0: 1: 2: 3: 4: 5: 6: 7: 8: 9: full
1: 2: 3: 4: 5: 6: 7: 8: 9: 10: full
2: 3: 4: 5: 6: 7: 8: 9: 10: 11: full
3: 4: 5: 6: 7: 8: 9: 10: 11: 12: full
4: 5: 6: 7: 8: 9: 10: 11: 12: 13: full
5: 6: 7: 8: 9: 10: 11: 12: 13: 14: full
6: 7: 8: 9: 10: 11: 12: 13: 14: 15: full
7: 8: 9: 10: 11: 12: 13: 14: 15: 16: full
8: 9: 10: 11: 12: 13: 14: 15: 16: 17: full
9: 10: 11: 12: 13: 14: 15: 16: 17: 18: full
10: 11: 12: 13: 14: 15: 16: 17: 18: 19: full
Buffer Size: 10
10: 11: 12: 13: 14: 15: 16: 17: 18: 19: index too large

start++: 11
cstart(start)++: 12
--start: 10
Start is mybuf.begin
Push!
Start is no longer mybuf.begin
after push, start: 11
forwards:  11: 13: 15: 17: 19:
backwards: 100: 18: 16: 14: 12:
mybuf[0]: 11
Push!

12: 13: 14: 15: 16: 17: 18: 19: 100: 20:
pop: 12
new front: 13 new size: 9
last: 20
13: 14: 15: 16: 17: 18: 19: 100: 20:
pop again: 13
last: 20
14: 15: 16: 17: 18: 19: 100: 20:

clone: 100: 20:
begin[3] = 17

Hello World!
```

Comment: I modified my review, adding *some* more things, in fact there's a lot of fix to apply :)

Comment: class `ring` is not movable, because it has `const` member.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Coding idiomatically

- **Remember that [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) isn't standard (unlike [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)).**

  - If you only intend your class works on major compilers, you can use `#pragma once` (but care about [defects](//stackoverflow.com/a/26908048/2644192) and [drawbacks](//stackoverflow.com/a/34884735/2644192))
  - If you wish your class works on all compilers, [use both `#pragma once` and the include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144110/2644192).
  - If you want your class to be 100% compatible with standards, use only include guards.
  - For completeness, I have  to mention [redundant include guards](//stackoverflow.com/questions/2233401/) too, which you could combine (or not) with `#pragma once`.
- **Don't misspell `size_t`**

  - You should use the full qualified `std::size_t` instead of just `size_t`, because [it's the standard way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813700/difference-between-size-t-and-stdsize-t).

---

### Coding with style

- [**Try to put `public` members first**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308581/how-should-i-order-the-members-of-a-c-class/308592) **(primarily a matter of personal preference)**

  - That makes your interface more explicit.
  - When users read your header file, they directly know what your class does.
  - That's what is adopted in a lot of coding standards ([google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Declaration_Order), [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CppConventions#C.2B-.2B-_Coding_Conventions), ...)
- **Be consistent**

  - In your methods' order (e.g. you shuffled `front`/`back` overloads )
  - In your spacing (e.g. look at your `operator`s' definitions)
  - In your members initialization alignment (It's really odd how you place the first member init on the same line that constructors signature, and other at the line, aligned with asserts)
  - In your naming (Why are all types "`snake_case`" but `circularBuffer` is "`camelCased`"?)

---

### Design choices

- **Type aliases**

  Why are the member type aliases (`value_type`, `reference`, ...) made private?
- **Naming**

  Use explicit name (`ring_iterator` instead of `my_iterator`, `container_type` instead of `circularBuffer`). Avoid useless function aliases (`pop_front()`, `push_back()`, `top()`).
- **Reconsider methods**

  Are `increment_head()`, `increment_tail()` or `full()` are really useful?
- **Consider computing `size` at compile time**

  If you don't need to allow `size` to be computed at runtime, consider making it `constexpr` or template parameter. It will allow some optimizations.
- **Maybe an oversight**

  Where are `crbegin`/`crend` ? Did you forget them? And what about `swap` or a `max_size` method?
- **Underlying container type**

  Did you considered using a [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) as inner data type?

---

### Checking again

---

#### A second look

- You really have a lot of formatting problems (too much or missing space, disgraceful indentation/alignment, ...). I think you have to consider adding a formatter in your tooling. [There's ton of options](//stackoverflow.com/questions/841075). You can also complete your toolbox using some "[static code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C,_C++)" application and trying to compile on multiple compilers with a selected set of flags to get useful warnings.
- Consider [adding the keyword `explicit` for constructors callable with one argument](https://foonathan.net/blog/2017/10/11/explicit-assignment.html).
- You don't have to `#include` `<iostream>` nor `<exception>` in your ring's header, as you use nothing from them in your class.
- You don't include `<iostream>`, `<algorithm>` and `<exception>` headers in the example file.
- Don't *implicitly* use `using namespace std` (using it is a mistake, but using it without writing it is even worse).
- Care about readability, even for example code.
- You have a *ninja* semicolon after the definition of `my_iterator::operator++()`

  ```
  my_iterator& operator++ ()
  {
      ++index;
      return *this;
  }; // <------ Here's the ninja!
  ```

---

#### Help the compiler to help you

- **Problem**: `error: field 'm_array_size' will be initialized after field 'm_head' [-Werror,-Wreorder]`
- **Solution**: Initialize members in order of their declaration

---

Once the `<iostream>` header removed :

- **Problem**: `error: 'out_of_range' is not a member of 'std'`
- **Solution**: Simply `#include <stdexcept>` in your `ring`'s header

Note that removing the `<exception>` header have no positive/negative effect on that, so keep it removed since you don't use it in your `ring` class.

---

- **Problem**: `error: implicitly-declared 'constexpr ring<int>::my_iterator<false>& ring<int>::my_iterator<false>::operator=(const ring<int>::my_iterator<false>&)' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-copy]`
- **Solution**: Simply define explicitly a copy assignment operator

---

- **Problem**: A lot of verbose errors coming from the `std::find` call in the example.
- **Solution**: Referring to [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) and [this post](//stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/) your `my_iterator` class have to provide a `value_type`member. `using value_type = typename std::conditional_t<isconst,T ,const T>;` should do the trick (or simply `T`).

---

- **Problem**: Another verbose error starting with `error: no match for 'operator-=' (operand types are 'const size_type' {aka 'const long unsigned int'} and 'const ring<int>::my_iterator<true>')`
- **Solution**: I think this is a copy/paste mistake. Here, the use of a subtraction assignment is pointless. just remove `lhs.index -= rhs;`.

---

- **Problem**: msvc complains about "assignment operator" and "move assignment operator" implicitly defined as deleted for `ring<int>`. (C4626 & C5027) (note: these warning are caused by the const-ness of `m_array_size`.)
- **Solution**: Consider implementing them.

---

- **Problem**: In `ring::my_iterator::operator[]` your parameter `index` hides the member variable `index`.
- **Solution**: For a global solution, use a decoration (e.g. post-fix with underscore) for your member variables. Otherwise, care about naming; here change the name of the parameter.

---

In your example:

- **Problem**: `catching polymorphic type 'class std::exception' by value [-Werror=catch-value=]`
- **Solution**: Catch exceptions using `const &` instead.

---

- **Problem**: You pass `10` (which is an int) as `size_t` (an unsigned integer type, e.g. `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`) to the constructor of `ring`.
- **Problem**: You use `push` 20 times `i` which is `size_t` into `ring<int>`.
- **Solution**: Use the right type at the right place, even in examples.

---

- **Problem**: You redeclare `i` in the nested "for-loop", already declared in the top-level one.
- **Solution**: Care about naming, even in examples. Here, the outside one can be named `value`: it's more explicit, and bonus, you might have noticed the typing problem.

Comment: I have thought about using **std::deque** and decided that **std::vector**’s contiguous memory guarantee and that three is no need for insertion in this class made that option less attractive. I am curious as to how you generated all of those compiler errors, I don’t see them, and thus I didn’t know to fix them (I use VS17).  
Based on your review, I have substantially revised my code. What is the community standard for showing my new _review inspired_ code? I would be very much interested in seeing if this c++  barbarian has understood all of your suggestions.

Comment: " What is the community standard for showing my new review inspired code?" Dunno, maybe post a new question, or a new reply to this question. Or wait response from a moderator ;)  For warning, I compiled on Clang/GCC with `-Wpedantic -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Warray-bounds -Weffc++ -Wstrict-aliasing`  and `/W4` on msvc. Used CppCheck too.

Comment: This is a good review, but point #1 about `#pragma once` is bad advice. It already was in 2018, and it definitely is now (I'm writing this in 2023).

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of `full()` should just be `return m_contents_size == m_array_size;`.

Similarly, make the implementation of `empty()` be `return m_contents_size == 0;`